# VBA Compile Error: expected =

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get an error for my code:

> compile error: Expected: =

```
DoCmd.OutputTo (acOutputReport, _
    ReportName & " " & Load, _
    acFormatPDF, _
    "\\drive\Reports\" & ReportName & " " & Load & " " & Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date)& ".pdf")
```

I have Access front-end and SQL-Server backend.

What do I need to do to fix this? I am still a beginner with VBA.

Answer (score 3):

You must call `Sub` procedures without parameter parentheses `( )` in VBA.

```vb
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, _
    ReportName & " " & MyLoad, _
    acFormatPDF, _
    "\\drive\Reports\" & ReportName & " " & MyLoad & " " & _
        Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date) & ".pdf"
```

Also `Load` is a reserved word in VBA. It is `Sub Load(Object As Object)`. Use another identifier.

---

The compile error "Expected: =" may seem awkward, but it makes sense, since parentheses are used for `Function` calls. I.e., VBA is expecting something like this

```vb
x = MyFunc(...)
```